# GAE SSL for custom domain impossible?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, ssl

I tried to configure SSL for my website that is served on GAE and failed.

http://www.gluwa.com/

works fine but

https://www.gluwa.com/

gives me nothing but an google error page.

[image]

After going over their SSL setup instruction several times now I am out of guesses.

I've tried both SNI and VIP but still no hope.

Is it impossible to have SSL for GAE apps?

EDIT:

I'm adding my settings as suggested by dragonx.

[image]

app.yaml

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
- name: PIL
  version: "latest"
- name: webob
  version: "latest"

builtins:
- django_wsgi: on
- appstats: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

handlers:
- url: /static/admin
  static_dir: admin_media/

- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
```

EDIT 2:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.django.main.app
  secure: always
```

I commented out below from builtins to add above handler.

```
- django_wsgi: on
```

However, adding this mark didn't solve the problem.

EDIT 3:

For more information, I followed below three steps to create my SSL certificate with openssl in my terminal.

```
$openssl genrsa -out yourdomain.com.key 1024
$openssl req -new -key yourdomain.com.key -out yourdomain.com.csr
$openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in yourdomain.com.csr -signkey yourdomain.com.key -out yourdomain.com.crt
```

and for the second command, I entered these information

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:KR
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Seoul
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Seocho
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Gluwa Inc.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:R&D
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:www.gluwa.com
Email Address []:gluwa@gluwa.com
```

I'm not sure if they should matter at all, though.

EDIT 4:

I tried using GAE server's information for creating SSL but it didn't worth either.

Comment: Have you read and followed the instructions? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Comment: Have you updated the CNAME records with your DNS provider?

Comment: yes, I did. Google required different CNAME for SNI and VIP so I tried both.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not impossible.  Works fine for me.

There's something you haven't configured properly.  You'll have to actually describe your configuration in detail for anyone to help you figure it out.

I'm guessing you didn't mark your request handlers as secure in your app.yaml.

Comment: You were also right that I didn't mark my request handlers as secure in my app.yaml. However, I'm only using them to serve static files so I guess there must be another way to mark other urls secure then using app.yaml.

Comment: Marking my request handlers as secure didn't solve the problem. I added my app.yaml with the marking above.

Comment: Your settings look mostly ok to me.  When I visit https://www.gluwa.com, I see the 503, as well as a bad certificate - the certificate is issued to *.google.com.  You should check whether the certificate that shows up in the browser matches the certificate you uploaded to Google.  If not, maybe file a production issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: I managed to repro the certificate problem on another site, so I don't think that's the problem.  Looking a little more closely, you're set up for SNI+VIP, but you didn't set up certificates for SNI.  Maybe try VIP only if you have your certicate there.

Comment: There are only 2 options: **SNI only** and **SNI+VIP**. I tried **SNI only** first since it's a cheaper choice. It didn't work. Google's telling that I am using **'0 out of 5 SNI slots'** because I am using **SNI+VIP** option. If I move it back to **SNI only**, it changes into '1 out 5'. I changed my CNAME back into **ghs.googlehosted.com**, also. Still, SAMO 503 error page.

Comment: I added the steps I followed to create my certificate in my question. I'm not sure if that should matter at all, though. Thanks for your help. Do you have anymore debugging suggestions for me?

Comment: Did you simply create the certificate yourself?  I'm not 100% certain, but I think that's probably the problem, since there's no certificate authority (CA) to validate your certificate.  You need to purchase an SSL certificate from a CA, like GoDaddy or Verisign.  There might be some korean companies that will do this too, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: I read other people using openssl for this job as I did, so I don't think that should be the problem. But if all else fails, I will try GoDaddy or etc. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, now I uploaded a certificate from GoDaddy and it results with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

your DNS entry is pointing to the wrong address:

```
$ host www.gluwa.com
www.gluwa.com has address 216.239.38.21
```

according to your screenshot it should be a CNAME to ghs-svc-https-c1099.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com.

when I try to access https://ghs-svc-https-c1099.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com I see your certificate, and if I send a GET request for www.gluwa.com to the server it returns some content from App Engine, so I think everything is configured correctly on Google's side.

Comment: what do you mean by "wrong address"? What should **host www.gluwa.com** return? And what should I do to make it correct?

Comment: you have an A record with a value of "216.239.38.21".

instead, you should have a CNAME record with a value of "ghs-svc-https-c1099.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com."

Comment: Sorry, I was iliterate. Now I see you said that in your answer. However, I don't understand why it should return CNAME record for **host www.gluwa.com**. **host www.github.com** also returns simple IP address **207.97.227.243**.

Comment: I didn't check this because you said you set your CNAME record already.  The browser gets redirected to the CNAME address, which provides the SSL certificate.  Whatever is at 216.239.38.21 is not providing the proper certificate.  Github's load balancer at 207.97.227.243 is providing their certificate.  Also, with Google's VIP, the actual IP could change.

Comment: I did set my CNAME record. Any guess why this is happening? I emailed google apps support. Let's see what they say.

Comment: No luck. "SSL configuration for custom domains isn’t part of the core services handled by the Google Apps Enterprise Support team." Now I'm totally out of hope.

Comment: you haven't configured your DNS entry properly and Google Apps Enterprise Support team couldn't fix that for you anyway.

you would be better off contacting your DNS provider, which looks like it is www.gabia.co.kr.

you should keep the IP 216.239.38.21 for the gluwa.com A record (it handles the redirect to www.gluwa.com on naked domains), but change www.gluwa.com to be a CNAME record to ghs-svc-https-c1099.ghs-ssl.googlehosted.com.

Comment: You were right. For some stupid reason, the CNAME was mapped to gae.gluwa.com not to www.gluwa.com. Now, the CNAME is mapped to www.gluwa.com. I checked it with **host www.gluwa.com** and it's set. However, it is still not working. Very strange.

Comment: I suspect it's because www.gluwa.com is redirected to 216.239.38.21 A record instead of my CNAME address. I'll try removing 216.239.38.21 just to check if that's the case. But then naked domain won't get redirected to www.gluwa.com.

Comment: just tested https://www.gluwa.com/ on chrome/mac and it serves the right certificate (issued by Go Daddy) and verifies ok.